# Why use DoFSCommand if one can just getUrl?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

I read it's possible to call any javascript
http://scriptplayground.com/tutorials/as/Call-Javascript-in-Flash/

so why would I need doFscommand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fscommand() was the only option to communicate between flash and javascript before External Interface was introduced.

more here:  http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14192.html#main_main_externalinterface

Comment: Thanks very usefull article didn't find it myself.